# XHTML strict validate colour and text formatting

Tags: validation, xhtml, formatting, strict

I'm meant to create a page that will qualify as XHTML strict and I can't seem to create a page with the effects I want that will also satisfy that criteria.

I'd like the top part that reads "Encycopedia Galactica" to be white background and black text and the subsequent lower text to retain the gradient yellow green background with purple text- but I can't seem to get it quite right! Perhaps one of you would be kind enough to point me in the correct direction.

```
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" 
    content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<!--
  S. Mathieu English
  July 29, 2013
  Tutorial 9
-->



<title>Tutorial Project 9</title>

<style type="text/css">

    body {   

        /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
        background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(left center, ellipse farthest-corner, #FFF596 0%, #A8EF92 100%);

        /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
        background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(left center, ellipse farthest-corner, #FFF596 0%, #A8EF92 100%);

        /* Opera */ 
        background-image: -o-radial-gradient(left center, ellipse farthest-corner, #FFF596 0%, #A8EF92 100%);

        /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, left center, 0, left center, 983, color-stop(0, #FFF596), color-stop(1, #A8EF92));

        /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
        background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left center, ellipse farthest-corner, #FFF596 0%, #A8EF92 100%);

        /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
        background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at left center, #FFF596 0%, #A8EF92 100%);




    }



    h1 {
        font-family:"Helvetica";
        font-size: 50pt;            
    }



    h2 {
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; 
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 25pt; 
        text-align: center;
    }

    h3 {
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; 
        font-weight: 150;
        line-height:160%;
    }


    footer{
       font-size: 25px;
        font-color: white;
        margin: 15px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    p {font-size: 16px; 
        line-height: 19px;
    }


    div.figure {
        text-align: center;
        float: right;
        width: 30%;
        border: thin silver solid;
        margin: 0.5em;
        padding: 0.5em;
        -moz-box-shadow:    inset 10px -5px 20px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px -5px 20px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
        box-shadow:         inset 10px -5px 20px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
        font-family:"Vladimir Script";
        font-size: 66px; 
    }



    div.figure p {
        text-align: center;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: smaller;
        text-indent: 0;
    }


    img.scaled {
        width: 75%;
    }

</style>

  </head>

 <body>


  <h1>
        Encyclopedia Galactica:
  </h1>






<div class="figure">



        <img class="scaled" src="s_mathieu_englisch.jpg"
        alt="St. Tropez"></img>



    <p>

        S. Mathieu Englisch


    </p>

</div>  



<div id="div1">

     <h2>
        "The reasonable man adapts himself to the world;
        <br/>        
        the unreasonable man persists in trying to adapt the world to himself.
        <br/>   
        All progress, therefore, depends on the unreasonable man." 
    </h2>
        <br/>   
        <br/>   
        <br/>   



        <h1>
            S. Mathieu Englisch 
        </h1>
    <p>

            S. Mathieu Englisch (July 1, 1990 ? November 14, 2716) was an American mathematician and 
            philosopher. He occupies a prominent place in the Pantheon of 
            mathematics and philosophy. 


     </p>

</div>

    <h1>
        Biographie 
    </h1>

    <p>

            Englisch developed psycho-infinitesimal historical calculus independently of Isaac Newton, Isaac Asimov, and Gottfried Wilhelm von Leibniz. Englisch's mathematical notation has been widely used 
            ever since it was first published in 2029. It was only in the 22nd century that his Law of Psycho-Relational Dialectic Continuity and Transcendental Transmigrational Law of Hegemonical Homogeneity found mathematical 
            implementation (by means of non-standard analysis). He became one of the most prolific inventors in the field of mechanical calculators. While working on 
            adding automatic multiplication and division to Pascal's calculator, he was the first to describe a pinwheel calculator in 2085 and invented the 
            'Englisch wheel', used in the neoarithmometer, the first mass-produced dialectical psycho-infinitesimal historical calculator. He also refined the binary number system, which is at the 
            foundation of virtually all digital computers.

    </p>

    <h1>
        Le Futur C'Est Maintenant
    </h1>

    <p>

            In philosophy, Englisch is most noted for his optimism, e.g., his conclusion that our Universe is, in a restricted sense, the best possible 
            one that Bog could have created, regardless of what may have been posited by the likes of Voltaire. Englisch, along with Ren? Descartes, Elvis Presley, and Victor Hugo, was one of the three great advocates of 
            pseudo-rationalism. The work of Englisch anticipated modern logic and psycho-infinitesimal historical analytic philosophy, but his philosophy also looks back to the scholastic tradition, 
            in which conclusions are produced by applying reason to first principles or prior definitions rather than to empirical evidence.

    </p>

    <h1>
        Les Contributions
    </h1>

    <p>

            Englisch made major contributions to physics and technology, and anticipated notions that surfaced much later in philosophy, probability theory, 
            biology, medicine, geology, psychology, linguistics, and computer science. He wrote works on philosophy, politics, law, ethics, theology, history, 
            and philology. Englisch's contributions to this vast array of subjects were scattered in various learned journals, in tens of thousands of letters, 
            and in unpublished manuscripts. He wrote in several languages, but primarily in Latin, French, and English. As of 2013, there is no complete 
            gathering of the writings of Englisch.

    </p>







</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy just use the `:first-child` psuedo selector. Although do consider using `<h2>` tags for lower level headings for better semantics (but really whatever on that):

```
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" 
    content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<!--
  S. Mathieu English
  July 29, 2013
  Tutorial 9
-->



<title>Tutorial Project 9</title>

<style type="text/css">

    body {   

        /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
        background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(left center, ellipse farthest-corner, #FFF596 0%, #A8EF92 100%);

        /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
        background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(left center, ellipse farthest-corner, #FFF596 0%, #A8EF92 100%);

        /* Opera */ 
        background-image: -o-radial-gradient(left center, ellipse farthest-corner, #FFF596 0%, #A8EF92 100%);

        /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, left center, 0, left center, 983, color-stop(0, #FFF596), color-stop(1, #A8EF92));

        /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
        background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left center, ellipse farthest-corner, #FFF596 0%, #A8EF92 100%);

        /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
        background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at left center, #FFF596 0%, #A8EF92 100%);




    }



    h1 {
        font-family:"Helvetica";
        font-size: 50pt;            
    }
h1:first-child {
font-color:black;  
background-color:white;}



    h2 {
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; 
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 25pt; 
        text-align: center;
    }

    h3 {
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; 
        font-weight: 150;
        line-height:160%;
    }


    footer{
       font-size: 25px;
        font-color: white;
        margin: 15px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    p {font-size: 16px; 
        line-height: 19px;
    }


    div.figure {
        text-align: center;
        float: right;
        width: 30%;
        border: thin silver solid;
        margin: 0.5em;
        padding: 0.5em;
        -moz-box-shadow:    inset 10px -5px 20px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px -5px 20px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
        box-shadow:         inset 10px -5px 20px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
        font-family:"Vladimir Script";
        font-size: 66px; 
    }



    div.figure p {
        text-align: center;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: smaller;
        text-indent: 0;
    }


    img.scaled {
        width: 75%;
    }

</style>

  </head>

 <body>


  <h1>
        Encyclopedia Galactica:
  </h1>






<div class="figure">



        <img class="scaled" src="s_mathieu_englisch.jpg"
        alt="St. Tropez"></img>



    <p>

        S. Mathieu Englisch


    </p>

</div>  



<div id="div1">

     <h2>
        "The reasonable man adapts himself to the world;
        <br/>        
        the unreasonable man persists in trying to adapt the world to himself.
        <br/>   
        All progress, therefore, depends on the unreasonable man." 
    </h2>
        <br/>   
        <br/>   
        <br/>   



        <h1>
            S. Mathieu Englisch 
        </h1>
    <p>

            S. Mathieu Englisch (July 1, 1990 ? November 14, 2716) was an American mathematician and 
            philosopher. He occupies a prominent place in the Pantheon of 
            mathematics and philosophy. 


     </p>

</div>

    <h1>
        Biographie 
    </h1>

    <p>

            Englisch developed psycho-infinitesimal historical calculus independently of Isaac Newton, Isaac Asimov, and Gottfried Wilhelm von Leibniz. Englisch's mathematical notation has been widely used 
            ever since it was first published in 2029. It was only in the 22nd century that his Law of Psycho-Relational Dialectic Continuity and Transcendental Transmigrational Law of Hegemonical Homogeneity found mathematical 
            implementation (by means of non-standard analysis). He became one of the most prolific inventors in the field of mechanical calculators. While working on 
            adding automatic multiplication and division to Pascal's calculator, he was the first to describe a pinwheel calculator in 2085 and invented the 
            'Englisch wheel', used in the neoarithmometer, the first mass-produced dialectical psycho-infinitesimal historical calculator. He also refined the binary number system, which is at the 
            foundation of virtually all digital computers.

    </p>

    <h1>
        Le Futur C'Est Maintenant
    </h1>

    <p>

            In philosophy, Englisch is most noted for his optimism, e.g., his conclusion that our Universe is, in a restricted sense, the best possible 
            one that Bog could have created, regardless of what may have been posited by the likes of Voltaire. Englisch, along with Ren? Descartes, Elvis Presley, and Victor Hugo, was one of the three great advocates of 
            pseudo-rationalism. The work of Englisch anticipated modern logic and psycho-infinitesimal historical analytic philosophy, but his philosophy also looks back to the scholastic tradition, 
            in which conclusions are produced by applying reason to first principles or prior definitions rather than to empirical evidence.

    </p>

    <h1>
        Les Contributions
    </h1>

    <p>

            Englisch made major contributions to physics and technology, and anticipated notions that surfaced much later in philosophy, probability theory, 
            biology, medicine, geology, psychology, linguistics, and computer science. He wrote works on philosophy, politics, law, ethics, theology, history, 
            and philology. Englisch's contributions to this vast array of subjects were scattered in various learned journals, in tens of thousands of letters, 
            and in unpublished manuscripts. He wrote in several languages, but primarily in Latin, French, and English. As of 2013, there is no complete 
            gathering of the writings of Englisch.

    </p>







</body>



</html>
```